# Creating a TCP socket connection and sending through a XML request in order to get an XML response?

Tags: php, xml, sockets, fsockopen

The port is 5792 and the ip is 123.123.123.123. I am able to send data to the ip, like so:

```
$host = "tcp://123.123.123.123"; 
$port = 5792; 
$errstr = '';
$errno = '';

$fp = fsockopen($host, $port ,$errno, $errstr, 30); 
if (!$fp) {
  print 'COULD NOT CONNECT! <br />';
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
  die();
}
else {
  print 'SUCCESS!<br />'
}
```

The sending seems to also work:

```
$message = 'hello';
fputs ($fp, $message );
```

The problem comes in when receiving data:

```
print fread($fp, 128);
```

This prints:

```
hello
```

... to the screen! So in other words, it's echoing what I'm sending it. Now, I know all messages are encapsulated within an XML element. Within this element a service request can be placed, which is also encapsulated in a XML element.

The encapsulated XML element is called "ROOT" and within this I can place the service request request. Let's call the actual service request I'm trying to accomplish "topUp".

1. Assuming there is a root xml element called ROOT, which encapsulates the service request "topUp", what would be the standard way to submit this XML as a string?
2. Is it normal to expect a server to echo your request whenever it can't understand what you are saying?

Comment: Both questions can only be answered if you tell what kind of server you're connecting to. If it's an HTTP server, you might want to look into `cURL`. If it's something custom, you tell us.

Comment: It's custom, so am I safe in assuming the only person that could tell me is the actual designer?

Comment: I changed my question a bit...

Comment: Yes, if it's something custom you'll have to contact the original developer, decompile / analyze existing code and / or look at an existing client. It might very well be programmed to simply echo back what it receives, noone can tell I guess.

Comment: Could you perhaps then rather help me figure out what is the standard way to submit XML to a socket like that?

Comment: There is no standard way to send XML over a socket, since XML is no protocol. You could try sending it over HTTP, using `cURL`.

Answer (score 1):

It is vital that u know the XML structure of the request command. In any case you can send you command in such a way too

```
 $message = "<root>"."\n";
 $message .= "<request>topUp</request>"."\n";
 $message .= "</root>"."\n";
 fputs ($fp, $message );
```

But unless you send your request structure defined you might not get the result you want.