# Sending a XML request to a socket

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to send a XML to a server in a TCP\IP (socket) connection.

My connection is okay. The sending part is the issue.

See below;

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$host    = "xx.xxx.xx.xxx";
$port    = xxxx;

// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
if($result === true){
    echo 'connected';
} 

$sendVendRequest='
<ipayMsg client="SAFEPAY" term="00001" seqNum="0" time=" '.date('Y-m-d   H: i: s').' +0200">
    <elecMsg ver="2.44">
        <vendReq>
            <ref>319155500001</ref>
            <amt cur="KSh">1000</amt>
            <numTokens>1</numTokens>
            <meter>A12C3456789</meter>
            <payType>cash</payType>
        </vendReq >
    </elecMsg>
</ipayMsg>';


$vendRequestXml=simplexml_load_string($sendVendRequest) or die("Error: could not create an object");
// print_r($vendRequestXml);
socket_write($socket, $sendVendRequest, strlen($sendVendRequest)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
```

The sending part fails. It loads until it times out. I suspect I am sending the request wrongly.. Someone please direct me on how to achieve this.

Comment: have you created tcp socket connection ?

Comment: @DeepKakkar the socket_create is okay... It connects very well. Well, unless I don't understand your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773769/creating-a-tcp-socket-connection-and-sending-through-a-xml-request-in-order-to-g

Comment: Do you see "connected"? Also a single socket_write wont be unough here, socket_write can return 0 or 10 or whatever bytes written. You need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$host    = "example.com";
$port    = 80;

// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
if($result === true){
    echo 'connected';
}·

$st='
<ipayMsg client="SAFEPAY" term="00001" seqNum="0" time=" '.date('Y-m-d   H: i: s').' +0200">
    <elecMsg ver="2.44">
        <vendReq>
            <ref>319155500001</ref>
            <amt cur="KSh">1000</amt>
            <numTokens>1</numTokens>
            <meter>A12C3456789</meter>
            <payType>cash</payType>
        </vendReq >
    </elecMsg>
</ipayMsg>';


$length = strlen($st);

while(true) {
  $sent = socket_write($socket, $st, $length);

  if($sent === false) {
    break;
  }

  // Was the entire msg sent?
  if($sent < $length) {
    // If not, handle the leftover data.
    $st = substr($st, $sent);
    $length -= $sent;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

echo socket_read($socket, 8192);
```

Can you telenet to that port?

Comment: Did u get any response?

Comment: Response from who? The author? The webserver?

Comment: From the web server

Comment: Yes, I got a response.

Comment: I followed your way and mine didn't return a response. I think now the issue is with Bitswitch system

Comment: Is "Bitswitch" expecting a HTTP request or just plain xml as this example shows?

Comment: It expects plain xml.

Comment: So it's not sent over http / https?

Comment: Yes. I thought you had implemented the same. It's a socket connection  where you send an xml as the message. It doesn't support soap, rest and http